# Find the area of the region bounded by the curves y = x^5 and y = 3x and the first quadrant

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, area

How can I find a bounded area in the first quadrant? And also I will do it by Mathematica. I tried several times, but I couldn't.

**What I have tried:**

```
NIntegrate[x^5, {x, 0, [Pi]}] - NIntegrate[3 x, {x, 0, [Pi]}] Plot[{x^5, 3 x}, {x, 0, [Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] RegionPlot[ y <= x^5 && y >= 3 x && 0 <= x <= [Pi], {x, 0, [Pi]}, {y, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 300] Area@ImplicitRegion[ y <= x^5 && y >= 3 x && 0 <= x <= [Pi], {{x, 0, [Pi]}, {y, 0, 200}}] % // N –
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: NIntegrate[x^5, {x, 0, \[Pi]}] - NIntegrate[3 x, {x, 0, \[Pi]}]
Plot[{x^5, 3 x}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
RegionPlot[ y <= x^5 && y >= 3 x && 0 <= x <= \[Pi], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 300]
Area@ImplicitRegion[ y <= x^5 && y >= 3 x && 0 <= x <= \[Pi], {{x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 200}}]
% // N

Comment: @KyleWilliamson I am not sure .Please help me Sir.

Comment: Please edit your question when you want to add information. You cannot format code properly in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The bounded area in the first quadrant extends to the intercept.

```
intercept = Solve[x^5 == 3 x, x][[-1, 1]]

(Integrate[3 x, x] /. intercept) - (Integrate[x^5, x] /. intercept)

Plot[{x^5, 3 x}, {x, 0, x /. intercept},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

RegionPlot[y >= x^5 && y <= 3 x && 0 <= x <= Last[intercept],
 {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]

Area@ImplicitRegion[y >= x^5 && y <= 3 x && 0 <= x <= Last[intercept],
  {{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 5}}]
```